# Stream audio from Windows to macOS with low latency

Tags: windows, streaming, macosx

I'm looking for a way to stream audio from a Windows system to a mac over my local network. I need it to be high quality and low latency, say less than 50 ms.

If I were streaming between two Windows systems I could use VBAN but it doesn't look like anyone makes a VBAN receptor for macOS.

Is there anything else I can use to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ OP

Isn't this what you need?

[vban receptor app](https://apps.apple.com/ph/app/vban-receptor/id1462414931?mt=12)

Comment: I didn't realize the author made a native mac version. He should advertise that on his website! Also, the Windows version of VBAN Receptor works in macOS using Wine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Dante Via by Audinate.

Comment: Hi Mark - can you articulate why or how so the OP can use this.